# Attaching unmanaged DLLs for use with VS Installer Packages

Tags: visual-studio, dependency-management

AN UPDATE: I'm using Advanced Installer now, because it's easier to learn/use and I'm on a time crunch. It somewhat auto-detects files better, but I'm still wondering about extra config/xml files needing included, and also now about some pre-install command line, but that'll be a different question.

Q:My application uses NuGet packages (Accord.Video.FFMpeg is the worst offender) that depend on a series on unmanaged dlls, exes, and even a PSpice library. I need these all to be packaged into one setup.exe (to be deployed on a different machine) that I'm building (no longer) using VS Installer Packages, but I can't get the installer project to recognize them as references.

My issue really is all the dlls that my packages depend on down the lane--Accord.Video.FFMpeg depends on these three exe files, which each depend on seven other dlls. All of them need to be ultimately combined at deployment.

I can't add these files using the Reference Manager. I've looked into making a second NuGet package that pulls everything together to just add that, but I'm not sure it's necessary. I've also tried 'adding the files as existing items,' but that hasn't gotten them to show up as dependencies in the installer project.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with C# packages for x64. Right now, all these files are in a libs folder in the debug folder of my project, and they've been 'added as existing files.'

The installer project recognizes all the highest level dlls, but I don't see how to force add more. Do I need to make each dll file's build action "Embedded Resource" and their copy to output directory "Copy if Newer"? Also, will I need to include related xml, config, pdb files I found for the NuGet dlls/packages? There's also a .dylib file and a .so file, but I'm not sure about those.

I've used the Dependencies application to find the links between Accord.Video.FFMpeg files.

Answer (score 0):

I was just building an installer this morning and had to add Prism dlls in this fashion.  Being reference from a project isn't enough to have the installer pick them up automatically.  If they won't be in the GAC on the target machine (due to being installed there by something else) then you will have to add them explicitly to your installer.

In order to add dll references that are external to your solution you will need to add them as separate component elements in your wix file.  Here is a brief example using log4net dependency.

Assuming a couple things:
1.  you have a Product.wxs file that refers to this component group C.Lib 
2.  you have a Lib.wxs file that contains this component group element definition:

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="CG.Lib" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="C.Lib">
            <File Source='$(var.Namespace.Of.Yours.TargetPath)' />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="C.log4net">
            <File Source='$(var.Namespace.Of.Yours.TargetDir)/log4net.dll' />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
```

3. The above is inside a wix fragment.

This example can be repeated for any number of dll libraries that you need to have installed.  just group them under the project that references them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I have a wix/wxs file to edit, though--the VS installer extension that I'm using has a cardboard box icon and is called "Installer Packages"; I got it from the VS marketplace. Am I misunderstanding? I haven't done a lot with xml before, but it's always time to learn.

Comment: use the "Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2017 Extension" and add a wix v3 installer project.  this will get you the basic setup.  the website for wix has a lot of information.  this is the only way I have done installers since they took the free ones out of VS several years ago.